# Spring Security: SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() returns null after user registering user and redirecting to after login page

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, security-context

After user is registered successfully, i am trying to redirect user to after login page and trying to get the Active user from SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication(); which is returning null.

Here is how i am setting context when user is successfully registered

```
 UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticatedUser = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails.getUsername(), userDetails.getPassword(), userDetails.getAuthorities());
 authenticatedUser.setDetails(userDetails);

 if(authenticatedUser.isAuthenticated()) {
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticatedUser);
 }
```

Then i am redirecting user to x page using response.sendRedirect(url);

In the controller method i am trying to the current user as

```
@RequestMapping("/<pattern>")
public @ResponseBody <method_name>(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse resp){
     Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if(auth==null){
            System.out.println("this is null");
        }
        else{
          // do something
        }
}
```

I am seeing the text in console as "this is null".

How to get retain the currentuser/Principal from SecurityContext() through out the user period till user logs out.

Comment: check [this](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/get-current-logged-in-username-in-spring-security/) to get current logger username. To get all details `User user = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();`

Comment: @user2264997 it was a typo error. I edited it now.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution.

The problem was with the pattern attribute for the  tag for that specific URI group.

Earlier it was /path/* and it was failing. I changed it to /path/** and it worked.

It would be helpful if someone can explain between these two pattern matching(/* and /**).

Comment: pattern attribute of http tag